# Sending data to Google Forms via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, google-forms

I would like to send data to a Google Form via an AJAX request.

I've already setup a Google Form and it is working fine when I use it from a direct link.

However, when I load the below page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello Google Forms</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js">
    </script>

    <script>

      // entry ids
      var entry_id_email = "entry.XXX";
      var entry_id_name  = "entry.XXX";

      // data to be sent
      var data = {};
      data[entry_id_email] = "foo@bar.com";
      data[entry_id_name]  = "Foo Bar";

      // form key
      var form_key = "XXX";

      // url
      var url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/" + form_key + "/formResponse";

      // ajax request
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/forms/d/XXX. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://myorigin' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: please check this https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000

Comment: that is the tutorial i am following. what should i change, specifically, in my code example to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling that you are using cross origin ajax request. So you need to change the atatype from **xml** to **jsonp**. This will fix your form submission issue. But you will get following error:

Refused to execute script from 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/key…ion%201&callback=jQuery111307080722744576633_1445478442168&_=1445478442169' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

This issue can not be fixed as er the udate [Cross Domain JSONP XML Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377804/cross-domain-jsonp-xml-response) .